# Active Directory group search C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm finding a group that is under a domain to see the group entered by user is valid or not. I have checked with few groups. it is working fine. But there is one group which is in the domain(I'm able to see it from AD) but still not succeding my code condition.

Can you please review if I'm missing something?

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain");
GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);
IsValidGroup = 0;
foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    if (found.ToString() == TxtAccName.Text)
    {
        IsValidGroup = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the essence actually. But your code is not feaseble. Try below, let me know.

```
bool groupExists;

using( var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain") )
{
    var filter = new GroupPrincipal(ctx) { Name = TxtAccName.Text }

    using ( var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(filter) )
    {
        groupExists = searcher.FindAll().Any();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting any result from groupExist variable. In quick watch, i'm seeing an error groupExist does not exists in the current context.

Comment: Thank you @Tolga Evcimen! I messed my code with Case functions (ToUpper/ToLower). Once i fixed it the issue was resolved.

Comment: Yes actually the filter I've provided handles them too. Upper/Lower cases and localization issues too. But in your code, it would require it to be equal letter by letter. Again I recommend you to use your `searcher` and `context` in using statements. Please click answer accepted tick if this post helped to solve your problem.